# How to invalidate container cache in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

Part of my Symfony app configuration is being loaded from legacy database, so sometimes I need to invalidate container cache to make use of updated data.

Is there any API to invalidate Symfony container cache programmatically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. As per `CacheClearCommand`:

   ```
   $filesystem   = $this->container->get('filesystem');
   $realCacheDir = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.cache_dir');
   $this->container->get('cache_clearer')->clear($realCacheDir);
   $filesystem->remove($realCacheDir);
   ```
2. Directly call CacheClearCommand from code:

   **services.yml**

   ```
   clear_cache_command_service:
       class: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\CacheClearCommand
       calls:
          - [setContainer, ["@service_container"] ]
   ```

   Than it's possible to do something like this (note that this will warmup the cache):

   ```
   $clearCacheCommand = $this->container->get('clear_cache_command_service');
   $clearCacheCommand->run(new ArgvInput(), new ConsoleOutput());
   ```